# Scala AKKA access variable or return a value

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Here is my code:

```
class testActor extends Actor   {
    var test = "test2"
    def receive = {
            case "test" ⇒ 
                    test="works"
                    "works"

    }
}


 def test = Action {
    var test = "test"
    val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
    val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[testActor.testActor], name = "testActor")

    myActor ! "test"

    test = myActor.test

Ok(views.html.test(test))
}
```

the line:
    test = myActor.test
doesn't work.

I either need a way to access what is returned by the actor function, in this case "works", or a way to access a variable inside the Actor.

Answer (score 9):

To return result to sender send a message to it back:

```
def receive = {
  case "test" => sender ! "works"
}
```

For waiting of response use Await.result() call:

```
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  test = Await.result(myActor ? "test", Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

Comment: I am getting this error with the second piece of code you gave me: could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout

Comment: sorry, missed to add implicit for timeout - please check latest version

Comment: thank you so much i am having the same problem now its solved after reading your answers thanks again :)

Comment: @user3801239 please don't overuse `Await.result`, which is blocking - use async callback handlers where is it possible instead. See more info and warnings about `onComplete`, `onSuccess`, or `onFailure` methods here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future